# Producers and consumers waiting indefinitely when the application should exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4

I have implemented a thread-safe blocking queue using a `QMutex` object, a `QWaitCondition` object for the producer thread and a `QWaitCondition` object for the consumer thread. The functions `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` are shown as follows:

```
void MyQueue::enqueue(const QString& s)
{
    _mutex.lock();

    while (_queue.size() == _maxSize) { _producer.wait(&_mutex); }

    _queue.enqueue(s);
    _consumer.wakeAll();

    _mutex.unlock();
}

QString MyQueue::dequeue()
{
    QString s;

    _mutex.lock();

    while (_queue.empty()) { _consumer.wait(&_mutex); }

    s = _queue.dequeue();

    _producer.wakeAll();
    _mutex.unlock();

    return s;
}
```

Consumer and producer threads that need to access this shared queue have a constructor that takes a reference to a `MyQueue` object. The above implementation works correctly, but problems arise when the main program must terminate, since some consumers or producers are waiting indefinitely, in particular:

1. If the queue is empty and a consumer has invoked the `dequeue()` function, this consumer will wait indefinitely.
2. If the queue is full and a producer has invoked the `enqueue()` function, this producer will wait indefinitely.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Have a state indicating the shutdown and read it after wakening a consumer or producer. After all producers have stopped wake all consumers until the queue is empty and all consumers have stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to handle termination can be using an atomic flag (you can use [std::atomic_bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or [QAtomicInt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qatomicint.html) ) and having  `_consumer.wait` use a timeout.

When you [detect a timeout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html) (`wait` returns `false` if a timeout occurred) check the flag if `cancel==true` then exit otherwise wait again. Thus in the worst case they will wait `time` milliseconds and then exit.

Answer (score 0):

If termination is the only issue, you can solve this by adding another condition to check for in the `while` loops:

```
    while (_queue.size() == _maxSize) {
        _producer.wait(&_mutex);
        if (_queue.shutting_down()) return;
    }
```

The queue could be augmented with an API that will set the shutting down flag, and then wake up any threads that might still be waiting on it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach that comes to mind is to provide a global boolean (`exit_now` or something) that you set to `true` and then broadcast to both condition variables to wake up. They wake up, check the boolean, and exit the thread.